# How to grey out / disable a button control in Win Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Can someone please provide an example of how to grey out a button control?

I have tried `DownloadButton.IsDisabled` and don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 53):

```
DownloadButton.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 17):

```
DownloadButton.Enabled = false;
```

Above code disables the button (It looks gray, and can't receive the click event)

Hope this is helpful!!

Answer (score 10):

Use this to disable a control:

```cs
DownloadButton.Enabled = false;
```

Use this to hide it entirely:

```cs
DownloadButton.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

```cs
DownloadButton.Enabled = false;
```

This will disable the button and make it fade out.